# Symfony $form is null

Tags: php, json, forms, rest, symfony

I've built an API GET function. The form looks like this:

```
<form action="/find" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="Title" id="Title" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

and this is my function which should handle the form above and insert string from the text box into `$form->get('Title')->getData()`. But when I try to GET using a browser, it gives me `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`. Looking at raw data, I get this:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>/home/vagrant/Code/symfony_awd/src/Blogsite/BooksBundle/Controller    /BookController.php:29:</small><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
</pre>Google Volume Not Found
```

I understand that the variable is null, but why? Here is the function code:

```
public function findAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(null, ['csrf_protection' => false])
        ->add('Title', TextType::class)
        ->add('Search', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    var_dump($form->getData());

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $json = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=".$form->get('Title')->getData());
        $response = json_decode($json, true);

        if(array_key_exists('items', $response)){
            return $this->render('BlogsiteBooksBundle:Pages:results.html.twig', [
                'items' => $response['items']
            ]);
        } else {
            return new Response('Google did not have any items', 400);
        }
    }

    return new Response('Google Book Not Found', 404);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the form is expecting the data to be sent through POST, you need to set the form's method to `GET`:

```
$this->createForm(null, ['csrf_protection' => false, 'method' => 'GET'])
    // ...
```

For more details please refer to [How to Change the Action and Method of a Form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html)